# How to speed up MYSQL query with multiple joins?

Tags: mysql

looking for help to speed up this query:

```
SELECT tickets.ticketid, datenew, products.name 
FROM tickets 
INNER JOIN ticketlines ON tickets.id = ticketlines.ticket 
INNER JOIN products ON ticketlines.product = products.id 
INNER JOIN receipts ON receipts.id = tickets.id 
WHERE (category !='feb765ef-c8a8-4fa2-969c-90f67fe6b3be' AND category!='888f4893-f300-43b5-9933-d549ade744e0' AND category !='8f2031e8-64a4-4abf-8175-3d2bedd9f950' AND category !='ca370ced-1c3b-434c-905e-ec1bc709543b' AND category !='f92ff0ac-fa11-4a5f-a3dd-e0d9ed9c171a' AND category !='445e8605-1cd9-4714-b3fd-7389ac29c206' and category !='05143c54-8a7e-4ce2-97cc-f84f9cf41395' AND category !='8c78afea-b9e2-44cf-b497-c384045b3202' AND category !='95919f7f-ff2e-4aa1-8110-ef63c022c01b' AND category !='f4f88b05-38a1-4956-9182-4c04a0808df7') AND datedone IS NULL 
ORDER BY ticketid
```

This is from a cash register database that I am using to pull data for order display.  The structure is the receipt has the primary id, the timein and timedone(DATEDONE) timestamps.  The ticket table has ticket id which is the same as receipt id.  Ticketlines table is the line items on the receipt/ticket.  And then Products table has the human readable definitions of the products.

The query is to pull all items that aren't completed, i.e. DATEDONE is null, and display the items that were ordered.

Ticket and Receipt tables have 15K rows, Ticketlines has ~20K rows, Products has 1.5k.

Pretty small data.  But this query takes over 20 seconds.  I think since I am using primary key IDs for everything, I don't need to index anything, but I am a total noob, so I'm happy to be told I'm wrong.  I'll appreciate any help and can provide any further details.  Thanks!

EDIT:

per comments, I am showing table structures.  I'm sorry for the formatting nightmare, I'm unfamiliar with this platform and unsure how to make it more readable :-(

```
| receipts | CREATE TABLE `receipts` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MONEY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DATENEW` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTES` mediumblob,
  `PERSON` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATEDONE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `RECEIPTS_FK_MONEY` (`MONEY`),
  KEY `RECEIPTS_INX_1` (`DATENEW`),
  CONSTRAINT `RECEIPTS_FK_MONEY` FOREIGN KEY (`MONEY`) REFERENCES `closedcash` (`MONEY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


| tickets | CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `TICKETTYPE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TICKETID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PERSON` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DONE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `TICKETS_FK_2` (`PERSON`),
  KEY `TICKETS_CUSTOMERS_FK` (`CUSTOMER`),
  KEY `TICKETS_TICKETID` (`TICKETTYPE`,`TICKETID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETS_CUSTOMERS_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER`) REFERENCES `customers` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETS_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PERSON`) REFERENCES `people` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETS_FK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `receipts` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


| ticketlines | CREATE TABLE `ticketlines` (
  `TICKET` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `LINE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITS` double NOT NULL,
  `PRICE` double NOT NULL,
  `TAXID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTES` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TICKET`,`LINE`),
  KEY `TICKETLINES_FK_2` (`PRODUCT`),
  KEY `TICKETLINES_ATTSETINST` (`ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID`),
  KEY `TICKETLINES_FK_3` (`TAXID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETLINES_ATTSETINST` FOREIGN KEY (`ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID`) REFERENCES `attributesetinstance` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETLINES_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT`) REFERENCES `products` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETLINES_FK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`TAXID`) REFERENCES `taxes` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TICKETLINES_FK_TICKET` FOREIGN KEY (`TICKET`) REFERENCES `tickets` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| products | CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `REFERENCE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CODE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CODETYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PRICEBUY` double NOT NULL,
  `PRICESELL` double NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `TAXCAT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTESET_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STOCKCOST` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `STOCKVOLUME` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMAGE` mediumblob,
  `ISCOM` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `ISSCALE` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `ISKITCHEN` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `PRINTKB` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `SENDSTATUS` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `ISSERVICE` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `ATTRIBUTES` mediumblob,
  `DISPLAY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PRODUCTS_INX_0` (`REFERENCE`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PRODUCTS_INX_1` (`CODE`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PRODUCTS_NAME_INX` (`NAME`),
  KEY `PRODUCTS_FK_1` (`CATEGORY`),
  KEY `PRODUCTS_TAXCAT_FK` (`TAXCAT`),
  KEY `PRODUCTS_ATTRSET_FK` (`ATTRIBUTESET_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `PRODUCTS_ATTRSET_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`ATTRIBUTESET_ID`) REFERENCES `attributeset` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `PRODUCTS_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CATEGORY`) REFERENCES `categories` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `PRODUCTS_TAXCAT_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`TAXCAT`) REFERENCES `taxcategories` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Also, here is EXPLAIN output:

```
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | receipts    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               | 14624 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tickets     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 767     | receipts.ID         |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ticketlines | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,TICKETLINES_FK_2 | PRIMARY | 767     | receipts.ID         |     1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,PRODUCTS_FK_1    | PRIMARY | 767     | ticketlines.PRODUCT |     1 |    97.97 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: You should index on the columns that are used in your joins. And I think you should index on the main columns you use in your `WHERE` clauses

Comment: Show us the full query, unedited.  We have no idea what you elided with `WHERE (a few AND statements of different category != [filtered out categories])`

Comment: @Martin My WHERE clause statements consist of 'category != '[excluded category1]' AND category != '[excluded category2]'...  I cut them out for brevity/readability.  Could I trouble you for an example line of indexing what to what?  I am just a bit at a loss of where to start exactly.

Comment: Also, your primary key is VARCHAR, whioch is also a very, very bad idea.

Comment: The DB schema is predetermined, by the primary application.  I've built an auxiliary app to use the data that is populated.  I can make it run faster by deleting rows, but I just feel that it should be running much faster than it is given the total rows i am working with.  If it's not reasonable for this query to return results within a second or two, then I will just accept that.

Comment: Pretty disappointed that my first post here was followed by 100 nits about formatting and info and when I fix and provide it all, I don't hear a peep.  @Sych, thanks for a least giving me a few suggestions to try, even if they didn't pan out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing data types of all columns to the minimal required ones.
Add indexes on columns in WHERE.
Add index on ticketlines.ticket.

Comment: *"Add index on ticketlines.ticket."* No need, the optimizer has already used the  `PRIMARY KEY ('TICKET','LINE')` because `TICKET` is first column in the index

Comment: I added category index to products table with no discernible improvement.   I had hoped indexing would be the solution but having read up further, I've only reinforced my initial belief that there's nothing to index here as everything is already being joined on primary keys.

Comment: The output of EXPLAIN suggests that you sort by something that is not primary key. You should not sort by `ticketid`, but by `tickets.ID`, if that is acceptable by application logic. Sorting by varchar is not the best idea, at least sort by date.

Comment: The returned rows are typically very small.  It should be in the dozens at most.  I removed ORDER BY altogether and but performance improvement is only  ~0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleted 10K rows from every linked table and it queries running in .2 seconds now.  I guess absent any more advice, i will be doing annual cleanup of old tickets.